# Set nvim to open in iterm2 when calling it in the command line

Tags: macos, neovim, iterm2

I am on a macOS, so I use iterm2 to run nvim since it supports true colors. However, I would still like to use the regular terminal for all other command line activities instead of iterm. Is there a way to permanently link or alias nvim so that when I call it in the command line in the macOS native terminal it opens in iterm?